# AJAX - Does BeforeSend always run immediately before Send

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please see the code below:

```
function GetSQLTable() {

            var str = $("#<%=fieldGroupReferences.ClientID%>")[0].value
            var res = str.split(",");
            var numSucceeded = 0;
            $("#LoadingImage").show();
            $("#LoadingImage2").show();
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.id = "div" + i
                document.getElementById('info_div').appendChild(div);

                var PossiblesPage = false;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "PrimaryNominalAjax.aspx/GetSQLTable",
                    data: '{username: "' + $("#<%=fieldUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", terminalname: "' + $("#<%=fieldTerminalName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", terminalip: "' + $("#<%=fieldTerminalIP.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", mappingid: "' + res[i] + '", usergroup: "' + $("#<%=fieldUserGroup.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", usn: "' + $("#<%=fieldUSN.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", requester: "' + $("#<%=fieldRequester.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", reason: "' + $("#<%=fieldReason.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", rrd: "' + $("#<%=fieldRRD.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", review: "' + $("#<%=fieldReview.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", possibles: "' + PossiblesPage + '",linkno: "", urn1: "", urn2: ""}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess(i, res.length),
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert('there was an error loading the webpage')
                    }
                });
            }
            function OnSuccess(i, totalrows) {
                return function (response) {
                alert(response.d)
             }}
```

Ajax is run multiple times.  I want to print the mapping id to the screen before it is run `e.g. mappingID + " is currently running"`.  MappingID is passed to the server during the AJAX request.  Is there an event that will allow me to handle this requirements? I have looked here: http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/.  Will BeforeSend handle it? i.e. does BeforeSend always run immediately before an AJAX request i.e. I do now want this to happen:

```
Before Send MappingID 1
Before Send MappingID 2
Send MappingID 1
Send MappingID 2
```

Comment: I believe you could have tested it far faster than it takes to write a question, but yeah, it should give that result.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté, I have tested it and I can confirm that it does not give that result!